# Anki shortcut to select / switch between decks

Tags: anki

In anki you can do pretty much everything with shortcuts. But one thing I could not find a shortcut for is selecting a particular deck from multiple decks in the decks window. I tried pushing all the direction keys as well as the tab button and their combinations with  <kbd>Alt</kbd>  and  <kbd>Tab</kbd>  but they don't work. It is good to be able to select a deck without using a mouse. Are you aware of such a shortcut (or if not, how to create one)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `/` key is the shortcut for the `Study Deck...` menu item.

[image: tools-menu]

Pressing that opens a drop-down with the deck list and a text entry box.

[image: deck-list]

Type the name to narrow the scope and `Enter` to open a deck